# Firebase Auth/Notification Realtime Database and Data Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

We're planning to implement `FireBaseAuth` and `Notifications`.
In the Free Package, it is mentioned that simultaneous connections with `RealTime Database` can be up to 100 and File Storage is around 5 GB.

What's the difference between RealTime Database simultaneous connection and File Storage(Uploaded / Downloaded / Stored)?

Which of these are used in case of `Auth` and `Notifications`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RealTime Database simultaneous connection and File storage are different thing then Auth and Notification.
There is no restriction on Auth and Notifications as they are not linked with either database or File Storage in Firebase

Comment: But where does it store the email and password. Is it like a free storage account like Drive and thus it doesn't matter how many users we can store there

Comment: As per their Console Users are stored on separate location than data.
It should be free of cost no matter how much user we stores. but there is cap on concurrent users.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Regarding concurrent users, it means as long as user is active in the app or once when user logs in. And secondly, how much is the cap limit

Comment: Concurrent user means online user who are using your app at same time and your app is connected to firebase through internet.
Suppose currently 
500 users have installed your app.
Right now 100 users have opened your app.
out of them 50 are on screen where you have called Firebase database listener.
out of 50 if 25 people are connected to internet then your concurrent users are 25.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.